# Why is my FloatingActionButton looking different?

Tags: xml, android-layout

I've created a FloatingActionButton and instead of the regular one, this is what came out [image]

This is my XML code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"

    android:layout_margin="16dp" />
```

I want the button to be like this normal one:

[image]

Comment: What version is the AppCompat dependancy in your gradle (Module) file? It should be at least 22+. For example, implementation 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in an image with an android:src attribute. You can add the actual image by Android Studio in the res/drawable folder.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"

    android:src="@drawable/{your image resource}"

    android:layout_margin="16dp" />
```

Comment: Thats not the problem, i've added the image and it still is that squared shape button, instead of the rounded one ahah

Answer (score 0):

The floating action button code looks like this peace of code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
      android:id="@+id/fab"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="top|end"
      android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
      android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomBar"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/contentContainer"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_receipt" />
```

The layout.xml should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".features.main.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- This could be your fragment container, or something -->
    <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/contentContainer"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomBar"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
      android:id="@+id/fab"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
      android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
      android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomBar"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/contentContainer"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_receipt" />

  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Make sure that your code looks like the xml code above.
If it doesn't have any issue related to the xml code, the error will be on Android Studio.

Comment: The FAB must be in a constraint layout? Because mine is a linear layout

Comment: In that example i'm using inside a constrant layout, but you can add this view in others layouts too.

Comment: Well, see my updated question please, there i explain better what i want

Comment: To be more specific i've added in my answer an example of xml file that includes a functional floating action button. I hope that you understand the example.

Answer (score 0):

Please sure about that you have added the dependency `implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'` in `build.gradle`(app).If not added then add it to build.gradle

After add the dependency,apply below code in layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:gravity="center">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope it work for you.